# Mongo Db query over collections with same datastructure in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to query over more collections with the same datastructure and therefore i need to combine the collections.

I have collections like Measurements2016 ,2017 , 2018 and so on.

But if i retourn the collections i only have the first collection in the IMongoQuerable List.

At the moment the code is this.

```
public IMongoQueryable<MeasureDocument> MeasureDocuments()
{
  IMongoQueryable<MeasureDocument> tmpCollection = database.GetCollection<MeasureDocument>($"Measurements2014").AsQueryable();

  for (int i = 2015; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
  {
    tmpCollection.Union(this.database.GetCollection<MeasureDocument>($"Measurements{i}").AsQueryable());
  }

  return tmpCollection;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't understand how Linq's method `Union` works. It doesn't modify the collection on which you call it (in this case `tmpCollection`). Documentation says:

> Produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality comparer.

It has a return type of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>` which is the actual union of the two collections.

Your code should look like this:

```
tmpCollection = tmpCollection.Union(this.database.GetCollection<MeasureDocument>($"Measurements{i}").AsQueryable());
```

---

### EDIT

It seems that `IMongoQueryable` doesn't support `Union`/`Concat` operations. Another option for you is to use fluent aggregation interface [IAggregateFluent](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluent_1.htm) which supports collection unions. But you lose some flexibility because it doesn't have all the `IMongoQueryable` functionality.

With IAggregateFluent your code would look like this:

```
public IAggregateFluent<MeasureDocument> MeasureDocuments()
{
    var aggregation = database.GetCollection<MeasureDocument>($"Measurements2014").Aggregate();

    for (int i = 2015; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
    {
        aggregation = aggregation.UnionWith(database.GetCollection<MeasureDocument>($"Measurements{i}"));
    }

    return aggregation;
}
```

Then if you want to filter the aggregation you can do something like this:

```
var filter = Builders<MeasureDocument>
    .Filter
    .Eq(m => m.Field, "2018");

var documentsOf2018 = MeasureDocuments().Match(filter);
```

And in the end you can call `ToEnumerable()` to enumerate the documents:

```
foreach (var document in documentsOf2018.ToEnumerable())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: It is not working it produces the exception:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NotSupportedException: The method Concat is not supported in the expression tree: aggregate([]).Concat(aggregate([])).
   bei MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   bei MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node) I have tried it with concat and union but nothing works

Comment: As you can see from the exception, IMongoQueryable doesn't support Union/Concat methods. But it supports `Join`, so you could try and use that.

Comment: Hello thanks, but i don't understand how i coudl reach that with join if i have in both collections the same datastructure? from the documentation i need a local and foreignfield but this is impossble if the datastructure in both collections is the same: $lookup:
 
 {
 
   from: <collection to join>,
 
   localField: <field from the input documents>,
 
   foreignField: <field from the documents of the “from” collection>,
 
   as: <output array field>
 
 }
 
}

Comment: @Rocky nevermind, I updated the answer. I tested it and it worked fine